problem connecting 8bitdo gamepad sf30 pro with my laptop
i'm trying to connect my 8bitdo gamepad. my bluetooth finds it, however when i try to click it so that it connects, it loads for a few seconds, then disappears without connecting. anytime i try again it just shows up as "not set up". why is this?
